# How to disable creation of token secret creation while creating a service account in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

When I create a service account in Kubernetes with the following specification

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: deploy-bot
```

It automatically creates the following secret with prefix `deploy-bot-token-XXXX`

```
$ kubectl get secret

NAME                                                      TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
default-token-lvq79                                       kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      60m
deploy-bot-token-7gmnh                                    kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      4m53s
```

Is there a way via which we can disable the automatic creation of secret tokens while creating service accounts?

Comment: what will be the  use of a service account if you dont want to create a secret associated with it ?

Comment: As best I can tell, [deleting its token Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/#to-delete-invalidate-a-serviceaccount-token-secret) will do what you want but there does not appear to be a way to do so cluster-wide, short of a [mutating admission controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#mutatingadmissionwebhook)

Comment: @confusedgenius, The reason for asking is that the token created has random suffixes, and I am creating an additional secret key via https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/#to-create-additional-api-tokens.

The reason why need to create an additional secret token with a deterministic name is that Cluster Pipelineresource of Tekton can utilize/refer it (Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/#to-create-additional-api-tokens) and decrease attack surface by not creating default/automatic secret token.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by modifying [`kube-controller-manager` options](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-controller-manager/).

The flag to be passed to the controller is `--controllers=-serviceaccount-token`. It will disable creating token for service accounts.

```
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-controller-manager
    - --controllers=-serviceaccount-token
 [...]
```

After this modification when you deploy your service account:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: deploy-bot

$ kubectl get sa
NAME         SECRETS   AGE
default      1         14m
deploy-bot   0         3s
```

and check the secrets created, you will notice that the secret has not been created:

```
$ kubectl get secret
NAME                  TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
default-token-t4qnv   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      14m
```

Comment: Thanks @Mariusz, The above does work but it will be applied to all secrets, is there a way where this behavior can be applied for specific secrets?

Comment: I'm afraid it won't be possible given that it disables token creation at cluster scope.

Comment: Thank @Maruisz for the confirmation and for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior you describe changes in Kubernetes 1.24, when the `LegacyServiceAccountTokenNoAutoGeneration` feature gate is enabled and new secrets containing service account tokens are no longer auto-generated.

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/72597897/901597