# A mountable secret and token are not automatically generated in serviceaccount

Tags: kubernetes, service-accounts

I downloaded Kubernetes for integration with Jenkins and created a Serviceaccount, but the secret is not automatically created.

In the past, I remember that a Secret was automatically created and the Token was mounted when Serviceaccount was created.

How can I automatically create a Secret as before?

Comment: In kubernetes  version 1.24 this behaviour is changed. Checkout official documentation or changelog.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72256006/service-account-secret-is-not-listed-how-to-fix-it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by @P.... In kubernetes version 1.24 this behaviour has been changed, the **LegacyServiceAccountTokenNoAutoGeneration** feature gate is enabled by default in 1.24.

New secrets containing service account tokens are no longer auto-generated and are not automatically ambient in secrets in 1.24+. Existing secrets containing service account tokens are still usable.

API clients scraping token content from auto-generated Secret API objects must start using the [TokenRequest API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/authentication-resources/token-request-v1/) to obtain a token (preferred, available in all supported versions), or you can explicitly request a secret-based token if a secret-based token is desired/needed.

Refer [manually create a service account API token](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#manually-create-a-service-account-api-token) to explicitly request a secret-based token.

Answer (score 5):

You can put the below two manifests into YAML files and and apply them or you can do it from the command line like this:

```
$ kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: jenkins-user
EOF


$ kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: jenkins-user-secret
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: jenkins-user
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
EOF
```

Here we have a secret which holds a certificate and a token:

```
$ kubectl get secret
NAME               TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
jenkins-user-secret   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      4s
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers above do not completely restore the pre 1.24 behaviour, however I have found that the below does restore it.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: jenkins-user-secret
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: jenkins-user
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: jenkins
automountServiceAccountToken: true
secrets:
  - name: jenkins-user-secret
```

This resolves the error I was previously seeing when running

```
istioctl x create-remote-secret
```

Which was throwing the error

```
Error: could not get access token to read resources from local kube-apiserver: no secret found in the service account:
```

The part missing in the answers above is configuring the service account to allow the secret to be used by pods by setting the "secrets" list.

Answer (score -3):

You can enabled it using the option `automountServiceAccountToken: true`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: jenkins
automountServiceAccountToken: true
```

else remove the option `automountServiceAccountToken` , by default it will create secret

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: jenkins
```

Comment: I think **this is not the right answer**. Since there is no auto generated secret what do you want to mount with that automountServiceAccountToken flag?

Comment: example:
    $ kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
    > apiVersion: v1
    > automountServiceAccountToken: true
    > kind: ServiceAccount
    > metadata:
    >   name: test-user
    > EOF
    serviceaccount/test-user created


    $ kubectl get sa
    NAME        SECRETS   AGE
    default     0         23h
    test-user   0         9s


    $ kubectl get secrets
    No resources found in default namespace.

No secret, no token.