# How to add Mountable secrets to a Service Account?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I realized ServiceAccount token secrets are no longer automatically generated in k8s 1.24. So I manually created a secret and attached it to the Service Account I created, but I found Mountable Secrets part is still empty, and I didn't find a way how to attach it to my Service Account.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: spinnaker-sa
  namespace: spinnaker
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
metadata:
  name: sa-token
  namespace: spinnaker
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: "spinnaker-sa"
    kubernetes.io/enforce-mountable-secrets: "true"
```

After I applied the above yaml file, I got the following result when I try `kubectl describe serviceaccount`

```
Name:                spinnaker-sa
Namespace:           spinnaker
Labels:              <none>
Annotations:         <none>
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   <none>
Tokens:              sa-token
Events:              <none>
```

Pls advise what I should do to add Mountable secrets. Thanks!

Comment: I think you'll find that even with `Mountable Secrets` showing `<none>`, the ServiceAccount token will still get mounted automatically into pods with `serviceAccountName: spinnaker-sa`.

Comment: @Iarsks, Spinnaker uses Halyard to deploy all the pods to k8s. I got permission error when Halyard tried to deploy them. That's why I suspect if it is something related with Mountable secrets, and I want to try it with Mountable secrets shows the secret. If Mountable secrets is not useful, please suggest what's the usage of it.

Comment: I think you can find your answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72597167/a-mountable-secret-and-token-are-not-automatically-generated-in-serviceaccount

Answer (score 0):

The blog post "[Understanding service accounts and tokens in Kubernetes](https://medium.com/@th3b3ginn3r/understanding-service-accounts-in-kubernetes-e9d2abe19df8)" by [th3b3ginn3r](https://github.com/th3b3ginn3r) mentions:

> In the K8s version before 1.24, every time we would create a service account, a non-expiring secret token (Mountable secrets & Tokens) was created by default. However, from version 1.24 onwards, it was disbanded and no secret token is created by default when we create a service account. However, we can create it when need be.

But: manually creating a secret and associating it with the Service Account does not automatically add it to the "`Mountable secrets`" list that you see when you inspect a `ServiceAccount` with [`kubectl describe`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#describe).

That behavior is expected, as the "Mountable secrets" list specifically refers to secrets that can be mounted by a Pod, whereas the Service Account token is used for API authentication and not for consumption within the Pod itself.

If you want to use the secret within a Pod, you will have to reference it in the Pod's specification. You can do this using the [`volumes` and `volumeMounts`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) sections.
You could mount the secret `sa-token` in a Pod like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: example-pod
  namespace: spinnaker
spec:
  serviceAccountName: spinnaker-sa
  containers:
  - name: example-container
    image: example-image
    volumeMounts:
    - name: sa-token-volume
      mountPath: /etc/sa-token
  volumes:
  - name: sa-token-volume
    secret:
      secretName: sa-token
```

With this configuration, the `sa-token` secret would be mounted into the `/etc/sa-token` directory inside the `example-container`. You can then use this secret within the container as needed.

Note that this process *still* does not affect the "`Mountable secrets`" section of the Service Account's description. If you want to use the secret within a Pod, you need to reference it in the Pod's specification, as shown above, rather than expecting it to be automatically available through the Service Account.